# Cannot filter Outlook AppointmentItem with start time

Tags: c#, outlook

This is my try to find an Appointment in Outlook calendar:

```
var calendar = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

if (calendar == null || calendar.Items == null)
{
   return null;
}

DateTime appointmentStart = new DateTime(2013, 04, 02, 10, 0 ,0);

string filter = string.Format("[Start] = '{0}'", appointmentStart );
var calendarItems = calendar.Items.Restrict(filter);
```

This way I cannot find the Appointmen in calendar, but I have one on 02 Apr. 2013 at 10:00:00.

Comment: Is your event of 2012.04.02 a recurrent one? Do you get is if you remove the call to `Restrict()`?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau - yes if I remove Restrict() the AppointmentItem is in the calendar.Items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg619398%28v=office.14%29.aspx), it seems that the date/time is not formatted correctly in your `filter` string:

```
string.Format("[Start] = '{0}'", appointmentStart);
```

returns `[Start] = '02/04/2013 10:00:00'`, while

```
string.Format("[Start] = '{0}'", appointmentStart.ToString("g"));
```

returns `[Start] = '02/04/2013 10:00'`

Note that this output will depend on the system culture (`fr-FR` in my case) which makes sense to me as Outlook should use the same.

More info about date and time format strings is available [on MSDN also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your response and for the links - I have aslo played with ToString() options .. maybe not enough.. Ill try it more - and let you know the result. Anyway I have upvoted for help )

Comment: this is exactly the answer: `string.Format("[Start] = '{0}'", appointmentStart.ToString("g")`

Answer (score 1):

Answered at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/8a8d6c59-20f4-4aeb-be0d-bfdc7b414611?prof=required:

Do not use "=" when searching on the date/time values. You will never get a match due to round-off errors. Use a range, e.g. (start > value - 1 minute) and  (start < value + 1 minute). Or, better yet, open the appointment by its entry id (Namespace.GetItemfromID) or search by another property (e.g. Subject).

Comment: Thnak you for the information about round-off (have upvoted).. My search based on time and one more parameter which is saved as a user property with AppointmenItem in calendar.

Comment: In my case I think there will be no round-off cause I create the Appointment Items programmatically and set the seconds part of the time to 00.

Comment: But anyway `(start > value - 1 minute) and (start < value + 1 minute)` is a good idea :)

Comment: Can you take a look please to my other question? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527280/cannot-filter-outlook-appointmentitem-with-start-time-range